# Swap keycodes in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard

I have a keyboard layout where greater and less signs is placed the wrong place in linux. In linux it's below escape, and it should (in my case) be at the right of left shift.

I have tried to use xmodmap, but it seems like there is challenges to also have the behavior of shift + keypress mapped.

How do i change swap keycode 49 and keycode 94 (plus shift etc. behavior)?

Comment: This is a case where posting a picture of your keyboard won't hurt. There are great chances that your layout is already supported, but X11/linux wrongly assumes a US one. Also run `xev -event keyboard`, press the problematic keys and other from the same rows, and edit the output into your Q.

Answer (score 1):

I found that to be able to swap keys, first get the identifiers by doing:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep 94
```

Keycode 94 in my case has the functionality that i would like to implement in keycode 49. Then I simply could do:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = less greater less greater backslash notsign backslash notsign"
```

Comment: If anyone wants this useless and redundant key to just be `Shift` when you accidentally press it: `xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L"`